# Javascript printing from nested arrays

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a random number generator script that will generate three numbers.  The first two numbers will be used to pick a "cell" in a "table" by referencing the row and column.  Within each cell are two numbers to choose from.  The third number will then determine which of the two numbers to select.  I have figured out most of this but I am having problems with the last part.

My "solution" was to create twenty arrays, and within each array are twenty more arrays.  Here is an example of the first array:

In the header I have the following:

Scripts to generate the first two numbers:

```
var randOne20 = Math.floor(Math.random()*20);
var randTwo20 = Math.floor(Math.random()*20);
```

Here is the first row of the 20 arrays:

```
var lvl1Roll1 = [[ 1,0 ],[ 1,1 ],[ 1,2 ],[ 1,3 ],[ 1,4 ],[ 1,5 ],[ 1,6 ],[ 1,7 ],[ 1,8 ],[ 1,9 ],[ 1,10 ],[ 1,11 ],[ 1,12 ],[ 1,13 ],[ 1,14 ],[ 1,15 ],[ 1,16 ],[ 1,17 ],[ 1,18 ],[ 1,19 ]];
```

The second row would be "lvl1Roll2" and the third would be "lvl1Roll3" etc. all the way up to "lvl1Roll20."

In the body I have the following script:

```
var randOne = randOne20 + 1;

document.write(window['lvl1Roll'+randOne][randTwo20]);
```

The randOne variable is used to select the appropriate row.

I can figure out how to select a specific cell (using the randTwo20 variable) but I have no idea how to then select the first or the second number within each cell.

Now, just to clarify, I have not listed the third random number generator code because at the moment I am just trying to figure out how to select either the first or second number within each cell.  Once I figure that out I can just use an if/else statement.

Also, if I did not want to print out the number but select it as a variable how would I do that?

Thank you for any and all help!

Take care and have a great day....

ciao,
john.

Comment: How about just add yet another bracketed index to the expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really not sure what you're trying to do, but... Getting the first of second element of an array is as simple as `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`, like so:

```
// First:
document.write(window['lvl1Roll'+randOne][randTwo20][0]);

// Second:
document.write(window['lvl1Roll'+randOne][randTwo20][1]);
```

To randomize, just follow the same pattern as before, but use [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) instead of [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) and don't multiply by 20:

```
var randOne20 = Math.floor(Math.random()*20);
var randTwo20 = Math.floor(Math.random()*20);
var randOne = Math.round(Math.random());

document.write(window['lvl1Roll'+randOne20][randTwo20][randOne]);
```

One more thing, though: you don't need to put the different rows in separate variable. You can just make it one big array:

```
var lvl1Roll = [
    [
        [ 1,0 ], [ 1,1 ], [ 1,2 ], [ 1,3 ], [ 1,4 ], [ 1,5 ], [ 1,6 ], [ 1,7 ], [ 1,8 ], [ 1,9 ], [ 1,10 ], [ 1,11 ], [ 1,12 ], [ 1,13 ], [ 1,14 ], [ 1,15 ], [ 1,16 ], [ 1,17 ], [ 1,18 ], [ 1,19 ]
    ],
    // [ lvl1Roll2 ],
    // [ lvl1Roll3 ], etc.
];
```

And use then use this to select a value from the table and put it into the variable `result`:

```
var result = lvl1Roll[randOne20][randTwo20][randOne];
```

And finally: I suspect that, I you were to tell us the logic behind the "rolls", it's quite plausible that you don't need this "table" at all. I could be wrong, but... might it be worth posting another question about that? Just a thought.

Comment: Thank you everyone for you replies.

PPvG, arr[0]/arr[1] is exactly what I was looking for.  I must have had a massive brain fart because I thought I tried that and did not get the result I was looking for.  I just tried it and it worked fine.  Thanks!

In regards to the random function, I should have mentioned that I am generating a random number between 1 and 20.

Comment: (Perhaps you tried `[1]` and `[2]`?) Call me daft, but... doesn't `1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*20)` do exactly what you need? It generates a random number between 1 and 20 (inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a random choice between two numbers (assuming 0 and 1), then:

```
var i = Math.random() < 0.5? 0 : 1;
```

or

```
var i = Math.random()*2 | 0;
```

should do the job. So:

```
document.write(window['lvl1Roll'+randOne][randTwo20][i]);
```

or

```
document.write(window['lvl1Roll'+randOne][randTwo20][Math.random() < 0.5? 0 : 1]);
```

or

```
document.write(window['lvl1Roll'+randOne][randTwo20][Math.random()*2 | 0);
```

How many do you want? :-)

Comment: Or just `Math.round(Math.random())`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly I think the easiest way to do this would be with one array that contained multiple arrays. The first would be the `table` array, each entry in the `table` array would be a `row` and each entry in a `row` would be a `cell`. This would make it really easy to reference any cell in the table. Here is a 3x3 example:

```
var table = [
    [0,1,2],
    [3,4,5],
    [6,7,8],
];

table[0][0]; // First Row, First Column, Equals 0;
table[1][1]; // Second Row, Second Column, Equals 4;
table[2][2]; // Third Row, Third Column, Equals 8;
```

You could actually push your 20 arrays into an array to create the table if you'd like:

```
var table = [];
table.push(randOne20);
table.push(randTwo20);
etc...
```

If you want to automatically load the arrays with random numbers you could easily do that with a loop.

```
var table = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++){ // Create 20 rows
    var row = [];
    for (var x=0; i<20; i++){ // Create 20 cells;
        var cell = [Math.round(Math.random), Math.round(Math.random)]; // Adds a two item array of random 0's or 1's
        row.push(cell); // Adds the cell to the row
    }
    table.push(row); // Adds the row to table
}
```